# R: Adding arrows to grids of layout

Tags: r, plot

I'm using layout to plot multiple things and I'd like to add arrow between some of these plots. I tried grid.curve and grid.lines() but no luck so far.
Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
mat <- cbind(matrix(c(1:3,0,4:5,0,6,7),3,3,byrow=T), 8:10)
m<-layout(mat)
layout.show(m)
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
trucks <- c(2, 5, 4, 5, 12)
plot(cars, type="o", col="blue")
plot(trucks, type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="red")
plot(cars, type="o", col="blue", ylim=c(0,12))
lines(trucks, type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="red")
barplot(cars)
barplot(trucks)
hist(cars)
pie(cars)
library(gplots)
textplot(mat)
```

I'd like to add an arrow from plot (layout.pos.col=2, layout.pos.row=1) to plot (layout.pos.col=2, layout.pos.row=2) and one from (layout.pos.col=2, layout.pos.row=2) to (layout.pos.col=3, layout.pos.row=3). Is there any simple way to add these?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

you could give `arrows` a go, if you don't require anything super fancy.
Two simple black straight arrows:

```
x <- -2
y <- -0.1
arrows(x0=x, y0=y, x1=x, y1=y-0.2, xpd=NA, length=0.05)

x <- -1.55
y <- -1.3
arrows(x0=x, y0=y, x1=x+0.5, y1=y-0.6, xpd=NA, length=0.05)
```

I figured out the coordinates entirely throught trial and error, there might be smarter ways.
`xpd=NA` is important to make drawing between plotting areas possible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but since my layout is a bit bigger than this one, figuring out the coordinates can be tricky and time-consuming. I tried some numbers but no arrows yet.

Comment: I think you can figure out the coordinates like this: `f <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...) arrows(grconvertX(x1, "ndc"), grconvertY(y1, "ndc"), grconvertX(x2, "ndc"), grconvertY(y2, "ndc"), xpd=NA, ...);getFig <- function(col, row, nrows=3, ncols=4) c(col*1/ncols - (1/ncols/2), 1 - ((row)*1/nrows - (1/nrows/2)) );do.call(f, c(as.list(c(getFig(1,1), getFig(2,2))), list(col="red")))`. Or you use `grid` to draw the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it in an elemental fashion.

```
:
textplot(mat)

par.old <- par(no.readonly=T)            # preserve old par
par(new=T, mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(0,0, type="n", axes=F, ann=F)       # make empty plot

a <- locator(4)                          # locator() returns xy coordinates at a click point
# click on the plot four times (first arrow's start point, end point, second arrow's …)

arrows(a$x[1], a$y[1], a$x[1], a$y[2], length=0.1)  # use same x ( a$x[2] is unnecessary ).
arrows(a$x[3], a$y[3], a$x[4], a$y[4], length=0.1)

par(par.old)
```

Comment: Thanks but this wouldn't work for me as I need to generate mutiple of these plots, so it doesn't make sense to use locator() each time, and also I'm using layout().